# Java Random number guessing game with dialog box

Tags: java, random, while-loop

Okay, I know this one has been asked before but I just can't figure out what is going wrong. Here are my instructions:

"Write a program that generates a random number between 1 and 1000 inclusively.  Then ask the user to guess what the number is.  If the user’s guess is higher than the random number, the program should display “Too high, try again.”  If the user’s guess is lower than the random number, the program should display “Too low, try again.”  The program should use a loop that repeats until the user correctly guesses the random number.
    Also, keep a count of the number of guesses that the user makes.  When the user correctly guesses the random number, the program should display the number of guesses.
Input and output should be done with Dialog and Message boxes. "

I have been working and reading all week on this and this is my second incarnation. I am at the point where my head is twisted around from all the reading. I get it to ask for a number in the dialog box and then nothing. What am I missing to keep the loop going? Please explain the what and why. Thanks in advance for looking.

```
import java.util.Scanner;        // Needed for the Scanner class.
import java.util.Random;         // Needed for the Random class.
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;  // Needed for JOptionPane.

/**
This program generates a random number guessing game.
*/

public class GuessingNumbersGame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
// Create an object and assign a whole random number 
// from 1 to 1000 to it.
        int rnumber;`
        Random randomNumbers = new Random();
        rnumber = randomNumbers.nextInt(1000) + 1; 

// Ask the user to guess the random number.
        String answer;
        int guess; 
        answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a whole  " +
            "number between 1 and 1000.");
        guess = Integer.parseInt(answer);
        int guesses;
        guesses = 0;                                                          

// Create a loop of user guesses versus the random number
// until the user answers correctly and keep track of the 
// number of times the user guesses. 
        while (guess != rnumber);
        {                                   
            if (guess > rnumber)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Too high, try again.");
                guess = Integer.parseInt(answer);
                guesses++;
            }            
            if (guess < rnumber)
            {                         
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Too low, try again.");
                guesses++;
            }  
        }       
        while (guess == rnumber)
        {                
            guesses++;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Congratulations! The correct " +
                "number is " + rnumber + ",and you had" + guesses + "guesses.");

        }

    System.exit(0);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Indent your code properly if you want people to try and read it.

Answer (score 0):

First, change `while (guess == rnumber)
{` to `if(guess == rnumber)
{` so that it only executes once.
As for your question's answer, you need to set guess and answer to something.
I would recommend doing this in the console, which would be to set answer to `java.util.Scanner.nextLine();` and then guess as the same thing. Not very easy doing it on JOptionPanes.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is not correctly constructed. There are few important issues with your implementation of the simple algorithm you were asked to write. It could be formulated this way (as some pseudo-code here):

```
begin

 guess <- 0
 guesses <- 0
 randnum <- new random number [1,1000]
 do
    guess <- ask user input
    guesses++
    if guess > randnum
        show "Too high"
    if guess < randnum
        show "Too low"
 while guess != randnum

 congrats  // guess = randnum
 show number of guesses

end
```

Your code doesn't look like this. Check your if-statements, conditions, and loops.